# NG-SELECT Have accessibility issues in Safari with Dropdown list item

Tags: html, angular, safari, accessibility, voiceover

I'm using the ng-select library in Angular and the issue is that, in safari, when using VoiceOver screen reader, there's a bug.

Screenshot:
In this screenshot, if I select Katy Wright, the screen reader will think that all items in the dropdown are Katy Wright, When I navigate with the arrow down, it keeps saying Katy Wright for all the items.

[image]

Has this happened to anyone while using safari ?

PS: It works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

I tried using a normal select and it works fine with HTML's "select - option."

PS: ng-select is not using the html semantic, select-option, they are using div with role=option instead of using the option tag.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/issues/947, which is not a direct webkit bug but is regarding another product, but it describes the same problem. That bug then references two webkit bugs:

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209076
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167671

Can you try selecting an option in the dropdown further down in the list, such as "Rosales Russel", and see if the elements before Rosales are announced but the elements after are not? That's what the "tailwindlabs" describes.

It works ok with VoiceOver on iOS. (I don't have a Mac to confirm it fails there.)

I tested with the example on https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources, which looks like your screenshot.

Note that the angular example does not properly implement the disabled elements in the dropdown list.  They need `aria-disabled="true"` on the elements that are not selectable.

[image]

Otherwise, their use of `<div role="listbox">` and `<div role="option" aria-selected="true|false">` is correct.

Comment: You are absolutely right, if I select Mendoza Ruiz, VoiceOver will work for Karyn Wright, Rochelle Estes and Mendoza Ruiz, but won't work for element that are under Mendoza Ruiz. 

So in conclusion, it's just a bug with VoiceOver/ Safari ?

Comment: It's probably just a bug with webkit/safari, in the way it surfaces the other elements.  VoiceOver is just reading what it's given so it's probably not a VoiceOver bug. You said it works in Chrome and Firefox (on the Mac) so those browsers are probably surfacing the elements correctly and thus VoiceOver works with them.